# GNUPLOT Inverse x and y axis for simple function

Tags: gnuplot, axes

I am plotting with GNUPLOT a simple hyperbolic-tanh so i defined f(x)=tanh(X)
and then I plot f(x), but I would like to rotate the graphic for 90 degree so that it Switch the axes (i.e. that the falues f(x) are on the x-axe). How can I do that?

Thank you for your help

Comment: @Thor no it is not a duplicate because in the article you linked they work with data... so I know how to do: 1:2 or 2:1 but here how can I do with a simple functino?

Comment: read more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple function use the parametric mode

```
set parametric
plot tanh(t),t
```

Comment: it does not work...

Comment: @MorganeMaPh: Works here